# how to set on update attributes in a timestamp field using dbforge class in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to set on update attributes for getting an updated time for my application. Here is my Model Code:

```
public function createDatabase() {
    $testdatabase = "testdatabase";
    $this->dbforge->create_database($testdatabase);
    $this->db->db_select($testdatabase);
    $fields = array(
        'id' => array(
            'type' => 'INT',
            'constraint' => 1,
            'unsigned' => TRUE,
        ),
        'name' => array(
            'type' => 'VARCHAR',
            'constraint' => '100',
        ),
        'establishment_date' => array(
            'type' => 'VARCHAR',
            'constraint' => '50',
            'null' => TRUE,
        ),
        'package' => array(
            'type' => 'VARCHAR',
            'constraint' => '15',
        ),
        'db_name' => array(
            'type' => 'VARCHAR',
            'constraint' => '25',
        ),
        'update_date' => array(
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'on update' => 'NOW()',
        ),
        'upgrade' => array(
            'type' => 'tinyint',
            'constraint' => '1',
            'default' => '0',
        ),
        'status' => array(
            'type' => 'tinyint',
            'constraint' => '1',
            'default' => '4',
        ),
    );
    $this->dbforge->add_field($fields);
    $this->dbforge->add_field("subscription_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
    $this->dbforge->add_field("subscription_expire TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'");
    $this->dbforge->add_key('id', TRUE);
    $this->dbforge->create_table('tms_profile');
}
```

Table is successfully created but on update attributes not exists on the field named update_date. i want to set on update atrributes on the field.

Comment: +1 to `$this->dbforge->add_field("subscription_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");` as an alternative to the `'default' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'` not working if it was part of `$fields` above

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is change `type` of `update_date` column like

```
....
'update_date' => array(
       'type' => 'TIMESTAMP'
 ),
.....
```

Now it will work ON UPDATE with `NOW()`

Answer (score 0):

use inline declaration, like here:

```
`update_stamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
```